# Unable to load ng2-tree using SystemJS.config.js

Tags: tree, angular5, systemjs

I am using Angular6.Have installed ng2-tree.However when I try to load the same , getting the below error -

```
fetch.js:32 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/uuid/v4 404 (Not Found)   
(index):23 Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://127.0.0.1:8080/uuid/v4
  Loading http://127.0.0.1:8080/node_modules/ng2-tree/src/tree.js
  Loading dist/main.js
    at fetch.js:37




Configurations - 
systemjs.config.js :
map: {
    "ng2-tree" : 'npm:ng2-tree',   
    ///bundles/ng2-tree.umd.min.js
  },
  packages: {

    'ng2-tree' : {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},   

  }


Component : 
import { TreeModel , TreeComponent , NodeEvent,TreeModelSettings } from 'ng2-tree';
```

Can someone suggest what needs to be done?
Do I need to update the config files??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the config file like this:

```
System.config({
    map: {
      'ng2-tree': 'npm:ng2-tree/bundles/ng2-tree.umd.min.js',
    }
}
```